# File doesn't exist but says it does?

Tags: java

Alot of people have the problem "Says File doesn't exist, but it does" but my problem is the opposite, the file doesn't exist but it says it does.
Unsure on how to solve this problem and other topics just come up with "File doesn't exist but it does", etc.

Here's my code:

```
package New;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
public class FileEditor {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Where is the file stored ex: C:/Users/Name/Place/filename.txt");
    String a = scan.nextLine();
    File file = new File(a);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
    BufferedWriter bwriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);
    if(!file.exists()){
        System.out.println("File does not exist.");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Start editing? y/n");
        String b = scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: How are you input the filename path? I mean, something like C:\tmp\my_file.txt ?

Comment: `FileWriter` will create the file if it doesn't exist...(and prepare to overwrite its contents if it does)

Comment: @IsmaelInfante I tried that with a file that didn't exist and some random letters, gave me the same reaction everytime. "Start editing" Which means  java thinks the file exists TT

Comment: @MadProgrammer .... wt

Comment: @INeedHelp Part of the process of creating a `FileWriter`, the writer checks to see if the file can be opened for writing, one of the consequences of is it makes the file if it doesn't exists.  Be a bit hard to write to a file which doesn't exists. This can be established from the JavaDocs, *"IOException - if the named file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, **does not exist but cannot be created**, or cannot be opened for any other reason"* - which means in order to be able to throw this exception, the writer must have attempted to create the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create the FileWriter/BufferedWriter until AFTER you verify the file exists.

Answer (score 3):

The file *does* exist. You're creating it right before you check whether it exists:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
```